# How to autoindent closing brace in vim

Tags: vim

I want to type

```
tag {
}
```

When I hit 'enter' after `{`, my cursor is 2 spaces indented (in column 3). (Tab is 2 spaces for me.) Then, when I type `}` (still in column 3), I want `}` to shift to column 1.

When I do this in a `.cpp` file, the cursor moves automatically to column 1.

When I do this in another file (`.wiki` in my case), it does not move. The `}` appears in column 3.

I thought this was controlled by 'autoindent' and 'smartindent', both of which are set in case of wiki file. What am I missing?

What other configuration information can I provide to help debug? How can I compare the configuration options between cpp file and wiki file?

(Edit for clarity: I am using the '.wiki' filetype defined in [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) plugin.)

Comment: Hm, this is a bit odd, when I set (manually, I don't think there's a filetype plugin for `.wiki` files among the default ones) `autoindent` and `smartindent`, the closing brace does get dedented. Are you sure the options are actually set?

Comment: Just tried it again. Explicitly setting 'smartindent' and 'autoindent' now. And it does not deindent `}` automatically. Is it possible that some other option affects it? I am using `vimwiki` and it defines the `.wiki` filetype. May be there is some setting vimwiki does that is messing it up?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) `vimwiki`, right? This is most interesting. By default, the plugin sets `nosmartindent`, so I don't get any indenting at all for the `tag` construct. If I set `smartindent`, I see the same behaviour as you describe. In a random file with no filetype with `autoindent` and `smartindent` on, I do get deindents. Curious, let me poke a bit more around this.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/autoload/vimwiki/lst.vim#L1444), and its analog for `<CR>`, seems to be the culprit. Basically, deindent doesn't happen if you type something, delete it and then type the closing brace. And it's exactly what this little evil thing is doing. Disable the mapping for `o` to get around this, not sure what to do about `<CR>` from the previous line, though, but probably something similar. This will break something in the plugin, probably. In fact, the comments in the source suggest that it is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Oh, and you should probably mention the plugin in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Michail. That was so quick of you to figure it out. 

How did you debug this by the way? Can you share some tool/debugger/script you use to debug vim scripts? Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you can copy the comments about 'o' and '<CR>' to an answer, I will accept the answer. Thanks so much again.

Comment: I will write up an answer shortly. I wish I could say that the debugging process was appreciably smart, but all I did was to compare the output of `:set` when run on a no-filetype file and a `.wiki` file, and meditate on `:help smartindent`. There were very little changes between the two, and none of those were mentioned to affect behaviour of `smartindent`. This, and "as the first character in a new line" part from the docs on `smartindent`, prompted me to run `map o` in a `.wiki` buffer. A call to the linked function popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the way the plugin handles lists' editing. Which is surprising, because the `tag { }` construct probably shouldn't be treated as one. To insert a new list marker, the plugin redefines a few mappings, they are mentioned in `:help vimwiki-lists`. Namely, `o` and `O` in normal mode, and `<CR>` in insert mode. Things they are mapped to have more-or-less the same behaviour when it comes to interaction with `smartindent`: they disable deindenting by inserting and deleting a dummy character on the new line (see, for example, [here](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/autoload/vimwiki/lst.vim#L1444)). This works because deindentation, as per `:help smartindent`, happens only if the closing brace is the first thing you type on the line.

This can be disabled by removing relevant mappings, but doing so will also break the lists system of the plugin. To fix *that*, you can duplicate those mappings using some other keys.

This might be worth discussing with the plugin's author, I don't think treating everything as a part of a list for indentation purposes is really what they indended.

Comment: Great debugging and thanks for the `:set` tip. It would be helpful in the future to compare options in two different buffers.